# Why am I getting output twice?

Tags: python, eclipse, python-3.x, pydev

Asking this question here, as the previous one was closed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41315555/traversing-a-linked-list-getting-the-output-twice

Update: I am using Python 3.6, Eclipse Neon.2 Release (4.6.2) (32 bit), and PyDev 5.5

I have created two classes, Node.py and UnorderedList.py.

Node.py is as follows:

```
class Node:
    #constructor
    def __init__(self,initdata):
        self.data = initdata
        self.next = None

    def hasNext(self):
        return self.next != None
```

UnorderedList.py :

```
class UnorderedList:   
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        self.last = None

    def append(self,data):  
        temp = Node(data)
        if(self.head == None):
            self.head = temp
            self.last = self.head
        else:
            self.last.next = temp
            self.last = self.last.next

    def traverse(self):
        current= self.head
        while current != None:
            print(current.data)
            current = current.next
```

I am testing it, using the following code:

```
ul = UnorderedList()
ul.append(1)
ul.append(2)
ul.traverse()
```

When I insert both classes in a single Python script, and run the code, the output, as expected, is:

```
1
2
```

However, when

1. I put the two classes in different modules, in the following package structure,

[Package structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWJSo.png)

2. put the import line on top of UnorderedList.py:

   ```
   import py_linked_lists.Node as Node
   ```
3. make changes to append() as follows:

   ```
   def append(self,data):
       temp = Node.Node(data)
       #rest all code remains same
   ```
4. Run the code, I get output twice:

   ```
   1
   2
   1
   2
   ```

Update: 
I tried out the suggestions in comments in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41315555/traversing-a-linked-list-getting-the-output-twice, and was successful in preventing the output from coming twice, by using the `if __name__ == "__main__"`
guard block, as follows, in UnorderedList.py:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

    ul = UnorderedList()
    ul.append(1)
    ul.append(2)
    ul.traverse()
```

Output:

```
1
2
```

Thanks to @Blckknght for that.

As i saw in the answers here, [What does if __name__ == "__main__": do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do), in case I do not use `if __name__ == "__main__"`, the `Node` class which I import from `py_linked_lists.Node` will also get executed.

What I am not able to understand is how execution of `Node.py` impacts the output, when there is no such code there, just a class structure present.

Comment: Neither here nor in the original question do you state what's in `__init__.py`. Is it empty?

Comment: `__init__.py` contains:
`import py_linked_lists.UnorderedList as UnorderedList`

Answer (score 3):

I got the answer, taking a cue from @nitind's comment.
I had the following in `__init__.py` of `py_linked_lists`:

```
import py_linked_lists.UnorderedList as UnorderedList
```

As I learnt from https://stackoverflow.com/a/448311/4515198, the package's `__init__.py` is loaded every time we run a a module in the package,

In this case, the `__init__.py` of `py_linked_lists` will be loaded before the module `UnorderedList.py` is executed. So, the module `UnorderedList.py` was loaded as a **import** from `__init__.py`, before being executed as the **main** module. Hence, I got the output twice.

To confirm, I added the following in `UnorderedList.py`:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Name is",__name__) 
    ul = UnorderedList()
    ul.append(1)
    ul.append(2)
    ul.traverse()
else:
    print("Name is",__name__)
    print("UnorderedList also being imported")
    print("---------------------------------")
```

the output:

```
Name is py_linked_lists.UnorderedList
UnorderedList also being imported
---------------------------------
Name is __main__
1
2
```

which clarifies that, `UnorderedList.py` was **first** loaded as in 
**import** from `__init__.py`, hence `__name__` was equal to `py_linked_lists.UnorderedList`, and so, the `else` part was executed.

Then, the module `UnorderedList.py` was loaded as the **main** module, hence `__name__` was equal to `__main__` and the `if` part was executed, justifying the output above.